# Am I converting JSON data to a Swift variable the long way?

Tags: json, swift3

I am reading json data from a file and trying to move it into a NSDictionary and I am wondering if there is a more concise way to do it. The code shown below works fine. In my program the Astruct-type variable  has more than 25 Bstruct-type variables. I have several files similar to the one I show. So it leads to a lot of cumbersome programming.

```
import UIKit

struct Bstruct {
    var label = String()
    var inputTypeStr = String()
    var list = [String]()
}
struct Astruct {
    // in real situation this has a over 25 variables
    // limited to 3 for this question
    var number = Bstruct()
    var customer = Bstruct()
    var location = Bstruct()
}

func loadJson(forFilename fileName: String) -> NSDictionary? {

    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
            do {
                let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                return dictionary
            } catch {
                print("Error!! Unable to parse  \(fileName).json")
            }
        }
        print("Error!! Unable to load  \(fileName).json")
    }

    return nil
}

func fillAstruct (value: NSDictionary) -> Bstruct {
    return Bstruct(label: value["label"] as! String, inputTypeStr: value["inputTypeStr"] as! String, list: value["list"] as! [String])

}
var aVar = Astruct()
let json = loadJson(forFilename: "document")! as NSDictionary
let d = json["aTemplate"]! as! NSDictionary
print("d = \(d)")

// load d into aVar, appears to be complex particularly if the variable has a large number of variables in aVar and the json file

for d1 in d {
    let key = String(describing: d1.0)
    let value = d1.1 as! NSDictionary
    switch key {
    case "number":
        aVar.number = fillAstruct(value: value)
    case "customer":
        aVar.customer = fillAstruct(value: value)
    case "location":
        aVar.location = fillAstruct(value: value)
    default: break
    }
}

print("\(aVar)")
```

The JSON file is shown below:

```
    {
  "aTemplate": {
    "number": {
      "label": "Number",
      "inputTypeStr": "selection",
      "list": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
      ]
    },
    "customer": {
      "label": "Customer",
      "inputTypeStr": "label",
      "list": [
        ""
      ]
    },
    "location": {
      "label": "location",
      "inputTypeStr": "label",
      "list": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A more concise way at least is to use native Swift dictionary and related enumeration functions. That saves a lot of type casting.

Comment: Any reference or hint on what I am looking for? Apple's Swift documentation shows a lot of functions. I am having difficulty understanding how to use it.